# Disable scrolling on logo overlay

Tags: html

I am looking to disable the scrolling on the overlay. The way this overlay is acting is to display a flashing logo before the users can actually display the website. But, I want scrolling disabled. Please take a look at my code to determine the error. I am looking to disable the scrolling on the overlay. The way this overlay is acting is to display a flashing logo before the users can actually display the website. But, I want scrolling disabled. Please take a look at my code to determine the error.

```
<html>
<head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:200,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
   #overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: dodgerblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;


}

* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;

}


    </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>//$( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast').delay(4500).fadeOut('fast');
            });</script>

        <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#navbar').fadeIn('fast').delay(4500)
            });

        </script>

<body>



    <div class="animated slideOutDown" id="overlay" style="overflow: hidden; text-align: center; animation-delay: 3s; animation-duration: 2.5s;padding-top: 80px; background-color: #181818;"><img class="animated flash" style="height: 350px; animation-delay: 1s; animation-duration: 1.5s;" alt="logo"></img></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When I run the code, I do not see a scroll bar. Is there something in animate.css that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the scrollbar for the body and prevent scrolling by adding "overflow: hidden;" to the html, body CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then you need to also set overflow back to auto once the overlay fades out, so you could do for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
        $('html, body').css('overflow', 'auto')
    }, 4500);
});
```

(Note: The way you are doing it, anyone with Javascript disabled will not be able to view your website. So you might want to consider how to make it viewable for those with Javascript off, even though that's a small % of people.)

Comment: That will disable the scrolling for the whole page, I'd like it just for the overlay.

Comment: Okay my apologies, I misunderstood because I don't see a scrollbar on the overlay when I try your code. You'll need to clarify or post a codepen or something for people to see what the problem is.